# Automate Build Active Architecture Only from 'YES' to 'NO' for Debug with React-Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am working on a React-native Project,

Everytime we upgrade React-Native or the Pods from `cocoaPods`, we have to set manually in every `.xcodeProj` the `Debug` option in `Build Active Architecture Only` in `project-> Build Settings` from `YES` to `NO` in order for the project to compile.

Is it possible to set them to `NO` programmatically or at once from XCode ?

**Note**: The `.xcodeproj` of React-Native are not Pods

Comment: You need to edit the tags

Comment: @zombie You are right, I removed carthage, cause it has nothing to do with the question (even if we plan on using it later)...But we are still using cocoapods and updating the Pods would be useful even if most of dependencies are not Pods.